# add class then remove it to add another class with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

this is my first question,and I would appreciate answer :)

I have a problem adding a class ".outro" with JQuery to the mega-dropdown.Im just starting learning ,and I cant find the solution... What I need is next: When I click on the .poslovni,I want to add or toggle class .intro on .mega-dropdown,witch I have done,BUT I would also like to remove that class and add the class .outro to the .mega-dropdown when I click again on .poslovni...Basicaly,I need animation when dropdown is opening,and I need it on dropdown closing... 
I hope I will get the answer soon,
Thanks!

Basic example:
HTML

```
<div class="poslovni">
    <div class="mega-dropdovn">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mega-dropdown {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 8%;
width: 84%;
box-shadow: 0px 6px 18px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
background: #000;
}

.intro {
display: block;
opacity: 0.8;
visibility: visible;
animation: animate 400ms ease-in forwards;
transform-origin: top left;
}
@keyframes animate {
 0% {
 transform: rotateX(-90deg);
 }
 100% {
 transform: rotateX(0deg);
 }
}
.outro {
display: block;
opacity: 0.8;
visibility: visible;
animation: ani 400ms ease-in forwards;
transform-origin: top left;
}
@keyframes ani {
 0% {
  transform: translateY(0px);
 }
 100% {
  transform: translateY(300px);
 }
}
```

and some very begginer looking JQUERY

```
$(function() {

$(".poslovni").click(function(e) {
    $(".mega-dropdown").toggle().toggleClass("intro");
    e.stopPropagation(); 

});
 $(document).click(function(e) {
    $('.intro').hide().removeClass('intro');
});
});
```

Again ,thanks for your time...

http://codepen.io/Bogdan986/pen/QKobEz

Answer (score 1):

```
$(element).toggleClass("intro outro");
```

This will remove class intro and add class outro. If you do that again, it will remove class outro and include class intro. Hope you want this

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function() {
    var disp = true;
    $(".poslovni").on('click', function() {
        $( ".mega-dropdown" ).toggleClass(function(){
            if (disp) {
                disp = false;
                $(this).removeClass('outro');
                return 'intro';
            } else {
                disp = true;
                $(this).removeClass('intro');
                return 'outro';
            }
        });
    });
});
```